# difference between .str.replace('[\$\,\.]', '') and str.replace('[.$,]','') in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, escaping

What is the difference between

```
car_sales["Price"]=car_sales["Price"].str.replace('[\$\,\.]','')
```

and

```
car_sales["Price"]=car_sales["Price"].str.replace('[.$,]','')
```

after removing the escape character this code works same and fine.
so, what was it's use.

Comment: Answer: `[.$,]` is a _character class_, and while dot and dollar sign are metacharacters, they do not need to be escaped when they appear inside a character class.  So, your first version, while correct, is superflous; you don't need to escape any of those characters with backslash.

Comment: thanks tim, i thought the same but you cleared